# Reading integer columns (Java) without using Arrays?

Tags: java, methods

I'm stumped on how I can read 3 different columns from a text file in Java to use them to a "grading" scheme.

```
46813  5  100.00
80795  4  86.52
34961  3  77.52
40059  2  85.61
80463  1  70.16
64088  0  80.52
65400  6  90.23
80775  2  70.16
573S1  3  83.03
21076  4  54.47
32911  5  -10.90
```

The first column is the student ID, the second being extra credit as an integer (resembling a percent. 1 = 1%), and the third is the grade.

I have:

```
static String inputFileName = "gradeInput.txt";
static File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        //validateFile(inputFile);
        validateData(inputFile);
    }
    public static void validateData(File inputFile) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner dataID = new Scanner(inputFile);
        int studentID = dataID.nextInt();
    }
```

For the validateData method, I just read the first int (student ID), not sure how to read the rest.

**Edit: **I just figured out on reading into the next int after "studentID". If I do like

```
int studentID = dataID.nextInt();
int extraCredit = dataID.nextInt();
double grades = dataID.nextDouble();
```

Can I go to the next line and repeat using a while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can loop over, [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) offer [`hasNextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()) method.

```
int sudentID,
    extraCredit;
double grade;
while(dataID.hasNextLine())
{
    studentID = dataID.nextInt();
    extraCredit = dataID.nextInt();
    grade = dataID.nextDouble();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I did, and I'm trying to validate the first column if it is an int or not; and if not, it will ignore it, but I'm not sure how to ignore non-ints? Like line 7 of the column sheet = "573S1"

Comment: Scanner also offer method `hasNextInt`, `hasNextDouble` etc